# Unable to set the log level of a child logger in winston

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I'm using winston as my logging library of choice in my node.js API. I create a child logger for each request with some default metadata like the request ID and user ID.

I want to only log `info` level log entries for these requests, which I can do by setting the logger level to `info`, however for some specific requests, like those by a specific user or when a param is passed, I'd like to log at a debug level for that child logger

I've tried setting the `level` property of my child logger, however this is ignored and debug entries don't get logged

Here is a code example:

```js
const winston = require('winston');

const mainLogger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({
            format: winston.format.combine(
                winston.format.colorize(),
                winston.format.printf((info: any) => `[${info.timestamp}] ${info.level}: ${info.message}`)
            )
        })
    ],
    silent: false,
    level: 'info'
});


mainLogger.info('Info level');
mainLogger.error('Error');
mainLogger.debug('This should not be logged, and it is not. Good!');

const childLogger = mainLogger.child({ metadata: 'value' });
childLogger.level = 'debug';
childLogger.debug('This should be logged, but it is not. Bad!');
```

How should I approach this? I've checked through all the documentation but I can only see info about adjusting the levels of the main logger and of the individual transports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only method I was able to achieve this is  to create a class of logger

```js
const winston = require('winston');

class Logger {
    constructor(level = 'info', metadata = {}) {
        this.logger = winston.createLogger({
            transports: [
                new winston.transports.Console({
                    format: winston.format.combine(
                        winston.format.colorize(),
                        winston.format.printf((info) => `[${info.timestamp}] ${info.level}: ${info.message}`)
                    )
                })
            ],
            level,
            defaultMeta: metadata,
            silent: false
        });
    }

    log(level, message, metadata = {}) {
        this.logger.log(level, message, metadata);
    }

    info(message, metadata = {}) {
        this.logger.info(message, metadata);
    }

    error(message, metadata = {}) {
        this.logger.error(message, metadata);
    }

    debug(message, metadata = {}) {
        this.logger.debug(message, metadata);
    }

    // Add more log methods as needed, e.g., warn, verbose, etc.
}

// Main Logger
const mainLogger = new Logger('info');
mainLogger.info('Info level');
mainLogger.error('Error');
mainLogger.debug('This should not be logged, and it is not. Good!');

// Child Logger
const childLogger = new Logger('debug', { metadata: 'value' });
childLogger.info('This is a child logger info');
childLogger.error('This is a child logger error');
childLogger.debug('This is a child logger debug');
```

Comment: Probably going to have to go with a solution like this, it's a shame it's not natively supported. With this method I can all of the classes share the same main logger and just use one instance per request, that way I avoid memory issues with having so many duplicate transports and instances of winston

Answer (score 1):

I beleive in Winston, the log level for each logger is determined by the level of the main logger, and it cannot be overridden at the child logger level. (I could be wrong)
But, there are alternative approaches you can choose from to achieve your goal. Instead of changing the log level of the child logger directly, you can use a custom log function that checks for specific conditions and then logs accordingly. Something like this

```js
// ... (existing code)

const childLogger = mainLogger.child({ metadata: 'value' });

// Custom log function for the child logger
childLogger.customDebug = function (message, options) {
    if (options && (options.debugUser || options.logDebug)) {
        this.debug(message, options);
    }
};

childLogger.customDebug('This should be logged because of logDebug option.', { logDebug: true });
childLogger.customDebug('This should NOT be logged.');
```

Or you can try filtering log levels based on custom conditions.

```js
// ... (existing code)
// Create a child logger
const childLogger = mainLogger.child({ metadata: 'value' });

// Log level for specific requests (e.g., user-specific or param-specific)
const DEBUG_LEVEL = 'customDebug';

// Log statements
mainLogger.info('Info level');
mainLogger.error('Error');
mainLogger.debug('This should not be logged, and it is not. Good!');

childLogger.log(DEBUG_LEVEL, 'This should be logged, and it is!');

// Log with custom message options
childLogger.log(DEBUG_LEVEL, 'This should also be logged with custom options.', { customDebug: true });
```

Hopefully one of these will work for you.